# Rails Resque workers in production - where to keep Redis server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, redis, resque, production-environment

I have Rails app configured with Resque and Redis. I am using God to start/stop workers. So far I was using Redis-to-go, but since I moved to an EC2 high-memory instance, I think it would be a better idea to run the Redis server on that EC2 instance and have all things happening there.

Is that a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We run our Redis instance (for resque) on the same server as the rest of our app. It's been great, and uses very little memory. But we only process about 5000 jobs a day.

Either way, assuming you are only using Redis for Resque, we've done it with extremely low overhead in CPU or Memory. Redis is very efficient as Resque storage.

Comment: Thank you! I actually came to same conclusion, but also did within 5K jobs / day.